# Membership Plugin with Facebook integration

Tags: login, facebook, membership

Any suggestions on a Plugin for Wordpress that can allow People to register and sign up for the site through a form as well as through facebook? Been searching around really only found one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Disqus Comment System](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/), which allows comment login using Google, Twitter, Facebook, or OpenID accounts, and is totally import/export compatible with WP comments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really recommend one as i haven't used any but a search in the wordpress plugin directory came up with a few results.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook+connect

Matt